# Promote npm packages in AzureDevops feed view from @local to @pre-release to @release, through shell/pyhthon/powershell script?

Tags: node.js, bash, powershell, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

How to Promote npm packages in Azure DevOps feed view from `@local` to `@pre-release` to `@release`, through shell/python/PowerShell script?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if this issue is still blocking you :)

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT

Thanks for asking 

Actually, I have tried the promote package tasks , but it will not work in my scenario. Because , I need to pass multiple packages with multiple versions in parameters.

Also, we cannot do it with script because we don't want to pass token or credentials in a script , it should bring the token or credentials automatically.

So I'm looking into customized promote task which should take multiple packages with multiple versions as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a script that does it with [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/npm?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), but there are two extensions that already did it:

1) [Promote package to Release View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.vsts-promotepackage-task)

2) [Promote](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Haplo.Promote)

Comment: These plugins will work for multiple packages as well as  multiple versions

Answer (score 0):

> How to Promote npm packages in Azure DevOps feed view from @local to
> @pre-release to @release, through shell/python/PowerShell script?

As **Shayki Abramczyk** said above, there already exists extensions to do that job. But if you do want a working PS script, here's mine:

```
$token = "Enter your Pat here"

$url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_apis/packaging/feeds/FeedID/npm/packagesbatch?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  "data": {
    "viewId": "Release"
  },
  "operation": 0,
  "packages": [{
    "id": "YourPackageName",
    "version": "PackageVersion",
    "protocolType": "Npm"
  }]
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

**Note:**

Enter your own PAT in `$token`, and replace the `OrgName, ProjectName, FeedID, YourPackageName, PackageVersion` with your own ones, you can set `PreRelease/Release` in viewID to promote npm packages in Azure DevOps feed view from `@local` to `@pre-release` to `@release`.

### Update 1

If you want to run it in Linux environment using bash, try using this script:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -X Post --user PAT:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YourOrgName/YourProjectName/_apis/packaging/feeds/YourFeedName/npm/packagesbatch?api-version=5.1-preview.1 \
--data '{ "data": {"viewId":"Release"},"operation": 0,"packages": [{"id": "YourPackageName","version": "YourPackageVersion","protocolType": "Npm"}]}'
```

To Generate PAT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat

Comment: Thanks for the help 

Just want to know one more thing, Can we do this with SHELL script also ?

Comment: Hmm, see [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2333#issuecomment-493663645), I think we can do this in shell script cause as I know bash can call curl command directly. But the syntax in shell script is different from that in powershell, so it may take some time to work on that. I'll come back when I can succeed to do that...